# Mapping self-referencing IDictionary<string, Entity> with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have the following entities in my domain model:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Foo : Entity
{
    public IDictionary<string, Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

class Bar : Entity
{
    public IDictionary<string, Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

class Attribute : Entity
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to map these dictionaries with Fluent NHibernate. I've gotten most things to work, but first I'm having difficulties with the self-referencing `Attribute.Attributes` property. This is due to NHibernate making the `Key` a primary key of the `Attribute` table as well as the `Id` it inherits from `Entity`. This is how my mapping works:

```
ManyToManyPart<Attribute> manyToMany = mapping
    .HasManyToMany<Attribute>(x => x.Attributes)
    .ChildKeyColumn("AttributeId")
    .ParentKeyColumn(String.Concat(entityName, "Id"))
    .AsMap(x => x.Key, a => a.Column("`Key`"))
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

if (entityType == typeof(Attribute))
{
    manyToMany
        .Table("AttributeAttribute")
        .ParentKeyColumn("ParentAttributeId");
}
```

If I replace the `if` statement with the following:

```
if (entityType == typeof(Attribute))
{
    manyToMany
        .Table("Attribute")
        .ParentKeyColumn("ParentAttributeId");
}
```

I get the following exception:

> NHibernate.FKUnmatchingColumnsException : Foreign key (FK_Attribute_Attribute [ParentAttributeId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Attribute [ParentAttributeId, Key])

This is due to NHibernate automatically making `Key` the primary key alongside `Id` in my `Attribute` column. I'd like `Key` to not be primary key, since it shows up in all of my many to many tables;

```
create table FooAttribute (
    FooId INT not null,
    AttributeId INT not null,
    [Key] NVARCHAR(255) not null
)
```

I'd like the foreign keys to only reference `Id` and not `(Id, Key)`, since having `Key` as a primary key requires it to be unique, which it won't be across all of my `ManyToMany`s.

Answer (score 1):

- where do you map `Attribute` itself (does it contain a Composite Key)?
- `AttributeValue` may be a better name to show that it contains a value.
- `.AsMap(x => x.Key)` is enough to say that Key should be the dictionary key

  ```
  create table FooAttribute (
      FooId INT not null,
      AttributeValueId INT not null
  )
  ```

or consider using

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Attributes)
    .KeyColumn(entity + Id)
    .AsMap(x => x.Key)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

which will create

```
    create table Attribute (
        Id INT not null,
        FooId INT,
        BarId INT,
        ParentAttributeId INT,
        Key TEXT,
        Value TEXT,
    )
```